# Render html immediately after Jquery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, append

I have a loop look like this

```
for(i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
    $('body').append("<div>lol</div>');
}
```

In Opera Browser I can See the element div with content  "lol" being "appended" in screen.

But in Chrome, Firefox, IE etc I can see the divs only when loop arrive end

How force them to work with Opera work using Js/Jquery or other client-side solution ou POG???

Comment: If you use a `window.setTimeout` or `window.setInterval` construct to give the browser time to update the view it'll work how you want.

Comment: What's wrong with "appended"?

Comment: @ascii-lime The point, I think, was that the HTML that's being appended is an empty `<div>`, but the question says "I can see the element div with "lol" being "appended" in screen."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, this is really bad practice. Each append forces a relayout and eats performance like cake.

That said, running a loop stalls UI updates. So just use an "async loop", a self referencing function with a timeout call to allow the UI to refresh.

```
var i = 5000;
var countdown = function () {
    $("body").append("<div></div>");
    if (i > 0) {
        i--;
        window.setTimeout(countdown, 0);
    }
}
countdown();
```

Edit: Added the actual function call.

Comment: It's late, so maybe I'm being stupid, but this doesn't actually call `countdown()` right?

Comment: +1 for pointing out how utterly bad an idea it is, finger wagging for declaring a function in Javascript's var syntax

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Well, `countdown` isn't called directly. It is passed as a reference to `setTimeout` which will call it when the time is up - in this case immediately or as soon as possible.

Comment: @TorstenWalter I think he means, you didn't start the loop because you didn't call it once.

Comment: there are other solution that i dont stop to use for loop?

Comment: @user1591287 No, for loops (in compliant browsers) should run without pause.

Comment: @TheZ there is [endless debate](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) as to why the `function` statement is broken. I prefer the best of both worlds normally, that is using `var` for named functions like so `var foo = function foo(){};`

Comment: @TorstenWalter Ignoring the fact that most of the examples that seem to break expectation are things that I wouldn't be doing in my code, very enlightening! Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 0):

use a recursive function with a setTimeout. The setTimeout lets the browser update the UI between DOM updates.

```
function appendDiv(iteration, iterationLimit) {
   $('body').append('<div></div>');
   if(iteration <= iterationLimit) {
      window.setTimeout(appendDiv, 1, iteration + 1, iterationLimit);
   }
}
```