# Display a message while loading Boostrap tabs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'm using tabs with Bootstrap, and I want to show a message while a tab is loading, but it's not working; the message is only shown when the tab is loaded.

HTML

```
<div id="loading_text">&nbsp;</div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-default" id="tabs" style="border-top-right-radius: 3px;border-top-left-radius: 3px;">
    <li id="ong1" class="active"> <a href="#ind_qualserv" id="lien_ind_qualserv" data-toggle="tab">Onglet 1</a></li>
    <li id="ong2" ><a href="#ind_incident" id="lien_ind_incident" data-toggle="tab">Onglet 2</a></li>
    <li id="ong3" ><a href="#ind_probleme" id="lien_ind_probleme" data-toggle="tab">Onglet 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="cont_ong1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="tab-pane"        id="cont_ong2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="tab-pane"        id="cont_ong3">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
```

Javascript for a tab

```
$("#ong1").click(function(e) {

    //  Loading information
    $("#loading_text").append('tab 1 is loading');

   // My function replaced here by sleep
    sleep(2);

    // Loading is finish, unshow message
    $("#loading_text").empty();
     $("#loading_text").append('&nbsp;');

});
```

I wan't to do this :
- Show message
- Function to build tab
- Hide message

See : 
    http://jsfiddle.net/jor7onr9/

Tab1 & Tab2 : on click on a tab we can't see message (because show and hide)
Tab3        : on click, the message appears at the end

Answer (score 1):

Since javascript only has one thread, it appears that the browser is occupied by performing the function and does not have time to render the update.

One possible solution is to let the page render by calling the function asynchronously:

```
// Click on tab1
$("#ong1").click(function(e) {

    //  Loading information
    $("#loading_text").append('tab 1 is loading');

   // My function replaced here by sleep
    window.setTimeout(function() { 
        sleep(2);
        $("#loading_text").empty();
        $("#loading_text").append('&nbsp;');
    }, 50);

});
```

A working fiddle is here : http://jsfiddle.net/jor7onr9/3/

Also see [Render html immediately after Jquery append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909040/render-html-immediately-after-jquery-append)